# CSS multiple class selector

Tags: css

I'm a beginner in CSS and I have a bit of a problem. I'm a bit confused on how to select the specific class and element in a nested div classes. So how do I select the `p` element on class "`team-position`".

minimal code:

```
<div class="filter_email-marketing-coordinator">
CONTENT
   <div class="inside card>
   CONTENT
       <div class="team-item">
       CONTENT
           <div class="team-item-con">
           CONTENT
               <p class="team-position">
               I WANT TO EDIT HERE.
               </p>   
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _call_?

Comment: a google search for CSS beginner tutorials would help

Comment: there's half a dozen bad practises here. (1) far too much inline styling (2). using !important tags (3). Bad formatting (although that could be down to C+P)

Comment: hi i've edit the code to minimal. sorry bout the mess up.

Comment: @CarlzManz what is it you want to edit exactly?

Comment: What do you want to do that can't be achieved by just using `.team-position` as your CSS class selector?

Comment: @MrCoder the class="team-position" from it parent class="filter_email-marketing-coordinator" coz the one that i showed is only a portion of my css and i dont want it to affect other classess only on that specific class.

Comment: add another class. Adding multiple classes to a single div is easy: `<p class= "myclass1 myclass2">this will have two classes attached</p>`

Comment: @TylerH yes. yes if i use .team-position. it affects the whole team-position classes. what i tried to achieve is to edit ONLT the class team-position in class filter_email-marketing-coordinator

Comment: @CarlzManz have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/am91mo4d/) - should explain a few things for you

Comment: thank you for the help guys. how do i mark this as resolved?

Comment: @CarlzManz Click the checkmark icon to the left of Namrehs' answer. Well, that's the normal method; I'm not sure if you can do that to a question that is on hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div.filter_email-marketing-coordinator p.team-position {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000000;
 }
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. what i meant was calling that specific class using that parent class filter_email-marketing-coordinator down to its descendant class team-position.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.  I have edited my answer.  Does that work for you?

Comment: thank you! this is what i was seeking. may i ask why the other class were not included you went directly to that class?